# Jquery mobile: Unable to animate the page background

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi i am implementing a jquery mobile application , i want the first page backgroungd to animate like this in the [**link**](http://www.makdeniz.com/source/moving_background/index.htm)

i am unable to implement this in my jquerymobile page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="b" >
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>helo</h1>
    </div>
 <!-- Start of content -->
    <div data-role="content" id="target-content" >  


    </div>
    <!-- end of content -->

     <!-- start of footer -->
        <div id="homeFooter" class="controlsFooter" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">

            <div style="width:100px; margin:auto;">
            <div class="center-wrapper" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">

              <a href="#page2" data-role="button" style="margin: 0.2em; data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-mini="true">Next</a>            
            </div><!-- end of center wrap -->
    </div>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

     <!-- end of footer -->   
</div>
```

Below is the code of **Mr.Murat Akdeniz**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="author" content="aaaaa" />

    <title>Moving Background</title>
</head>

<body>
<style>


        body
                {
                    height: 100%;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    background: #fff url(back2.jpg) repeat-x scroll right bottom;
                    background-color: #fff !important;
                }


</style>

<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var scrollSpeed = 60;       // Speed in milliseconds
            var step = 1;               // How many pixels to move per step
            var current = 0;            // The current pixel row
            var imageWidth = 1024;      // Background image width
            var headerWidth = 280;      // How wide the header is.

            //The pixel row where to start a new loop
            var restartPosition = -(imageWidth - headerWidth);

            function scrollBg(){
                //Go to next pixel row.
                current -= step;

                //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
                if (current == restartPosition){
                    current = 0;
                }

                //Set the CSS of the header.
                $('body').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
            }

            //Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
            var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It pretty much works as is.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5P8fX/2/)**

```
var scrollSpeed = 60; // Speed in milliseconds
var step = 1; // How many pixels to move per step
var current = 0; // The current pixel row
var imageWidth = 1024; // Background image width
var headerWidth = 280; // How wide the header is.
//The pixel row where to start a new loop
var restartPosition = -(imageWidth - headerWidth);

function scrollBg() {
    //Go to next pixel row.
    current -= step;
    //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
    if (current == restartPosition) {
        current = 0;
    }
    //Set the CSS of the header.
    $('body').css("background-position", current + "px 0");
}

//Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
var init;
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    clearInterval(init);
    var init = setInterval(scrollBg, scrollSpeed);
});
```

In CSS, you set the body background and in order to see it, your need to set the jQM page and content backgrounds to transparent:

```
body {
    height: 100%; padding: 0;  margin: 0;
    background: #fff url(http://lorempixel.com/1024/1000) repeat-x scroll left top;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
[data-role=page], .ui-content {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

UPDATE: OP has asked for the image to go back and forth instead of one direction.

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5P8fX/3/)**

```
var reverse = false;
function scrollBg() {
    //Go to next pixel row
    if (reverse){
        current += step;
    } else {
        current -= step;
    }
    //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
    if (current == restartPosition) {
        reverse = true;        
    }
    if (current == 0) {
        reverse = false;        
    }
    //Set the CSS of the header.
    $('body').css("background-position", current + "px 0");
}
```

Comment: hi,thank you .. i want the image to move left to right after reaching the end of the right ,i mean to say move image back and forth..can u please let me know how to implement it

Comment: @teekib, see my updated answer and demo. A simple change - http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5P8fX/3/

Comment: hi i can see itz working for you in you demo but my screen is not at all moving

Comment: hey its working..thank you soo much...one small query , what should be the size of the image now i am using 1024x685, but the image is spliting so how large the image should be.

Comment: What do you mean by splitting? I guess the size would depend on what screen size you are supporting. You can also play with the headerWidth. Make it bigger to have less animation, e.g. 900 as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5P8fX/4/